# What prevents mtd from being read?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, embedded, linux-device-driver

I have a small program which I'm using to attempt to read out the details of the MTDs on my embedded Linux platform. I'm running into problems where most blocks can't be read and I'm not 100% sure why this is happening.

A check of the `/dev` directory shows 8 `mtd`s all with the same permissions:

```
# ls -al | grep "mtd*"
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      90,   0 Jan  1  1970 mtd0
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      90,   2 Jan  1  1970 mtd1
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      90,   4 Jan  1  1970 mtd2
...
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      90,  14 Jan  1  1970 mtd7
```

My application is also running as root:

```
# ls -al mtd_test
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        19688 Nov 30 01:18 mtd_test
```

Checking the `/proc` I can see that 7 of the 8 mtd's are mounted (so I expected `mtd7` to fail to be read)

```
# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00020000 00020000 "u-boot (128 kB)"
mtd1: 00020000 00020000 "u-boot Environment (128 kB)"
mtd2: 00040000 00020000 "Reserved (256 kB)"
mtd3: 00200000 00020000 "Kernel (2048 kB)"
mtd4: 00000064 00020000 "rootFS header"
mtd5: 003fff9c 00020000 "rootFS (4096 kB)"
mtd6: 00180000 00020000 "Permanent Storage (1536 KB)"
```

Oddly, only `mtd1` and `mtd6` were able to be read, all the others failed with an error "Permission denied", does anyone have any idea why this would be?

I doubt it's my code, but here it is:

```
int main()
{
    mtd_info_t mtd_info;
    int count, fd;
    char devs[][15] = { {"/dev/mtd0"},{"/dev/mtdblock0"},
                        {"/dev/mtd1"},{"/dev/mtdblock1"}, 
                        {"/dev/mtd2"},{"/dev/mtdblock2"}, 
                        {"/dev/mtd3"},{"/dev/mtdblock3"}, 
                        {"/dev/mtd4"},{"/dev/mtdblock4"}, 
                        {"/dev/mtd5"},{"/dev/mtdblock5"},
                        {"/dev/mtd6"},{"/dev/mtdblock6"}, 
                        {"/dev/mtd7"},{"/dev/mtdblock7"}, };  
    for(count = 0; count < 16; count++) {
        fd = open(devs[count], O_RDWR);
        if(fd > 0) {
            ioctl(fd, MEMGETINFO, &mtd_info);
            printf("For dev: %s\nMTD Type: %u\nMTD total size: %u bytes\nMTD erase size: %u bytes\n",
            devs[count], mtd_info.type, mtd_info.size, mtd_info.erasesize);
            close(fd);
        }
        else
          printf("Failed for %s: error - %s\n", devs[count], strerror(errno));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using an *ext* family FS, the command `lsattr` works at a deeper level on access rights, but usually doesn't apply to `/dev/*` - you can try anyway. Besides, I'd try the `O_RDONLY` access instead of `O_RDWR`: some devices require a specific protocol to be written to. While reading may be freely allowed.

Comment: @ring0 - Thanks for the thought, but it's a [jffs2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFFS2), so no luck with the `lsattr` command... good point about the permissions however, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @ring0 - derpy derp... changed to `RDONLY` and it works. Now I need to see if I can figure out how to mount them such that they have write permissions too. Anyway, that's another problem. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: Chances are that all the MTD partitions besides mtd1/6 are write-protected in hardware. You may be able to change this, but doing so will put you at risk of bricking the device pretty badly.

Comment: FYI: Flash-memory *block devices* often become read-only, seemingly without any good reason. See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1125282) superuser.com question. This question is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123560/while-trying-to-open-dev-mtd2-for-read-write-access-permission-denied) in unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an ext family FS, the command lsattr works at a deeper level on access rights, but usually doesn't apply to `/dev/*` - you can try anyway. The *jffs2* FS [planned](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/diff/linux/fs/jffs2/ioctl.c?v=2.6.25;diffval=2.6.31.13;diffvar=v) to implement `lsattr` - not sure if they did.

The `O_RDONLY` access instead of `O_RDWR` could help for reading the memory - some devices require a specific protocol to be written to, while reading may be freely allowed.

Maybe playing with the `man 2 open` flags - like `O_SYNC` etc... - may help.

There is [this page](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/01/working-with-mtd-devices/) but the author uses `O_RDWR` as well.

Comment: `The jffs2 FS planned to implement lsattr` - totally correct, and it was indeed implemented; however on my embedded project I'm stuck in a 2.4 kernel, and there was no back port so I'm SOL.